# how to configure and access data on spark

Tags: apache-spark

friend this week i am very busy on installation and configuration of spark envirnoment  i did the installation and I begin basic operations like creating folder and adding text file to the folder,count the number of word found on the text file. however after i add csv file when i try access the data from the csv file i got the following error.
[image]